# Entity Framework OrderBy after GroupJoin impossible

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

I have a problem with an unwanted `ORDER BY` on Entity Frameworks `GroupJoin`.

But at first my query. Its a simple query chain with a JOIN and ORDER.

## First step - Simple condition query:

```
var dataQuery = model.InverterData
    .Where(d => d.Timestamp >= from && d.Timestamp < till)
    .Select(d => new
    {
        d.InverterID,
        d.Timestamp
    });
```

## Second step - OUTER JOIN query:

```
var dayDataQuery = model.InverterDayData
    .GroupJoin(dataQuery
    , outer => outer.InverterID
    , inner => inner.InverterID
    , (outer, inner) => new
    {
        outer.InverterID,
        outer.Date,
        outer.DayYield,

        InverterData = inner.Select(d => new
        {
            d.Timestamp
        })
    });
```

## Third step - ORDER BY:

```
var orderedQuery = dayDataQuery
    .OrderBy(d => d.DayYield)
    .ThenBy(d => d.InverterID);
```

My Problem now is that the GroupJoin builds up a query with an unwanted ORDER BY at the end. That made my order complete senseless.

But in details...

## This is the generated SQL after Step 1:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[InverterID] AS [InverterID], 
    [Extent1].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp]
    FROM [data].[InverterData] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Timestamp] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Timestamp] < @p__linq__1)
```

Looks good!

## Generated SQL after Step 2:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[InverterID] AS [InverterID], 
    [Project1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Project1].[DayYield] AS [DayYield], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[InverterID] AS [InverterID], 
        [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
        [Extent1].[DayYield] AS [DayYield], 
        1 AS [C1], 
        [Extent2].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[InverterID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
        FROM  [data].[InverterDayData] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [data].[InverterData] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[Timestamp] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].[Timestamp] < @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[InverterID] = [Extent2].[InverterID])
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[InverterID] ASC, [Project1].[Date] ASC, [Project1].[C2] ASC
```

An unwanted ORDER BY is added `ORDER BY [Project1].[InverterID] ASC, [Project1].[Date] ASC, [Project1].[C2] ASC`!

## Generated SQL after Step 3:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[InverterID] AS [InverterID], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Project1].[DayYield] AS [DayYield], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[InverterID] AS [InverterID], 
        [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
        [Extent1].[DayYield] AS [DayYield], 
        1 AS [C1], 
        [Extent2].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[InverterID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
        FROM  [data].[InverterDayData] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [data].[InverterData] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[Timestamp] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].[Timestamp] < @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[InverterID] = [Extent2].[InverterID])
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[DayYield] ASC, [Project1].[InverterID] ASC, [Project1].[Date] ASC, [Project1].[C2] ASC
```

My order (by `DayYield` and `InverterID`) will not work because `Date` and `C2` is now also include.

## Question:

Why and/or how can I make it work correct?
On-server order is need because on-server paging.

### Answer related to @IvanStoev

How do you mean this? Its made an huge different on the resulting order.
[image]

Comment: Why do you think your order will not work? The added order clause by EF (specific to how EF materializes detail subqueries) is applied **after** your ordering, so your ordering should not be affected.

Comment: @IvanStoev please see my detailed answer above.

Comment: Of course it will make difference for **equal** `(DayYield, InverterID)` combinations, but the order of SQL queries for non unique `ORDER BY` is undefined anyway. Since you don't specify unique ordering, the exact order should not be a concern.

Comment: And btw, EF makes it more deterministic which is crucial for correct paging. Anyway, this is how EF works with such queries, you have to accept it - there is no way to workaround it.